# How to build a custom TailwindCSS standalone executable?

Tags: node.js, tailwind-css

I want to use TailwindCSS in an environment without NodeJS, so I use the [single-file binary executable](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/standalone-cli). I also want to use `postcss-import` and `postcss-nested`, but since there is no NodeJS on this server, I cannot use Tailwind's recommended approach of specifying a custom postcss.config.js.

I therefore created my own fork of TailwindCSS, and [modified the default postcss.config.js stub to include postcss-import](https://github.com/webtourismus/tailwindcss-standalone-bundler/blob/master/stubs/defaultPostCssConfig.stub.js). Then using Tailwind's [Github "Prepare release" action](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/master/.github/workflows/prepare-release.yml) in my own fork, I created [my own single-file executables with postcss-import bundled](https://github.com/webtourismus/tailwindcss-standalone-bundler/releases/tag/untagged-e280f940eb9dd5ff5017). This worked as expected, imported CSS files are now inlined when using my custom executable.

I then tried the same trick again and also added tailwindcss/nesting to the postcss-config-stub, and sadly this did not work. I can see my nested CSS rules in the output, but they are not transformed to native CSS selectors, but rendered as written in the input CSS.

Can anyone help me getting `tailwind/nesting` respectivly `postcss-nested` bundled into the standalone CLI build process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally managed it. If anyone is interested, here are my patches

https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/compare/master...webtourismus:tailwindcss:patched

which I used to create my own little composer package, so I can use TailwindCSS on my PHP server without NodeJS

https://packagist.org/packages/webtourismus/tailwindcss-cli